# Странное сообщение при закрытии дубликата

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, дубликаты

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/53976

> Данный ответ отмечен как «низкокачественный» из-за длины и содержимого.

<s>Вроде раньше было более адекватное сообщение для дубликатов?</s>

Ну вот, запостил вопрос, а потом дошло, что это была проверка не в той очереди.

Тогда так: Может стоит исключать потенциальные дубликаты из других очередей?

> а что плохого в том, что ответ будет в двух или более очередях?

Там разное оформление для закрытия как дубликата и в низкокачественных. Я изначально из-за этого вопрос и задал, т. к. вместо вкладок с вопросом и вопросом-дубликатом, я увидел обычное сообщение о качестве вопроса.

Что было бы, если бы я случайно не заметил комментарий, в котором говорится о дубликате? На мой взгляд, вопрос нормальный, поэтому следует нажать "Выглядит нормально". Теперь представим, что так сделало несколько человек. Что дальше?

Если система понимает, что голоса из разных очередей не связаны, время проверяющих просто потрачено в пустую. А если не понимает, то закрытие как дубликата отклоняется из-за того, что вопрос не является вопросом низкого качества о_О

Получается, что нет смыла помещать вопрос одновременно и на закрытие как дубликата, и на проверку качества вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых ещё неизвестно, будет ли вопрос в итоге отмечен как дубликат. Как правило, один голос за дубликат приводит к закрытию. Но иногда и нет. Это не повод убирать вопрос из других очередей.

Во-вторых потенциальный дубликат может быть просто плохо оформлен. В очередях "низкого качества" и "новых сообщений" он получает лишние просмотры от опытных участников и шанс на улучшающую правку.

Comment: Я имел в виду не насовсем исключать, а на время проверки. Т. е. если он потенциально дубликат - то в этой очереди не показывать. Если незадубликатился, то вернуть. В той очереди его ведь так же поправить смогут.

Comment: @Qwertiy а что плохого в том, что ответ будет в двух или более очередях?

Comment: Вопрос дополнен.