# Надо ли вообще улучшать вопросы-дубликаты?

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

На основе [ответа](/a/2302/178988) на соседний вопрос

> Во-вторых потенциальный дубликат может быть просто плохо оформлен. ... он получает лишние просмотры от опытных участников и шанс на улучшающую правку.

А имеет ли вообще смысл улучшать вопрос, являющийся дубликатом. Случай, когда он дубликатом не является тут не рассматриваем. Вот есть вопрос, который в ближайшее время будет закрыт как дубликат. Что мы выигрываем внося в него перед этим правку?

Единственной полезной правкой в данном случае мне кажется вынесение кода в блок кода (кстати, в контексте того [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2300/178988), для этого лишние просмотры не нужны).

А есть ли что-то ещё, что полезно, но может остаться незамеченным?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конечно стоит.

- Добавить релевантные метки.
- Исправить орфографические и грамматические ошибки.
- Поправить форматирование кода. Просто чтобы не снижать общий уровень порядка на сайте.

Исключение — заголовки. Не нужно приводить все заголовки к одному виду, напротив стоит оставить оригинальную формулировку.

- Это облегчит поиск решения в будущем
- Формулировка проблемы — часть проблемы. Если поменять её, то вопрос перестаёт отражать образ мыслей спрашивающего и саму проблему.
- Конечно, орфографические и грамматические ошибки исправлять можно.

Подробнее об этом пишет jfs: [Правильная формулировка вопроса часто бывает половиной решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1403/181472).